# Maximum spectral radiancy dependency on temperature formula?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

I tried searching on the web but could not get a clear formula which relates maximum spectral radiancy and temperature of the body ( to which power of temperature it depends). Please tell me , I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @RobJeffries The law relating the max in the spectrum to the temperature is Wien's displacement law. The question I've linked asks how the max relates to temperature, just like this question, and the answers explain how Wien's displacement law gives the relationship.

Comment: No it doesn't. Both in the title and in the text the OP asks for the relationship between maximum spectral radiance and temperature, not the frequency/wavelength at the maximum radiance (which is obviously available everywhere).  @JohnRennie

Comment: Nice that this finally got an upvote. It is not something I have seen treated anywhere else. Other readers note that John Rennie has missed the point entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum spectral radiance (in frequency units) does indeed have a simple temperature dependence. The maximum radiance occurs at a frequency given by [Wien's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien's_displacement_law):
$$\nu_{\rm max} = 2.82 \frac{kT}{h}.$$
You substitute this back into the [Planck function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law) to work out the spectral radiance at this maximum frequency
$$f(\nu)_{\rm max} = \frac{2h (2.82kT/h)^3}{c^2} \left(\exp\left[\frac{h(2.82kT/h)}{kT}\right]-1\right)^{-1} = 2.84\frac{k^3}{h^2c^2} T^3$$
in units of W m$^{-2}$ sr$^{-1}$ Hz$^{-1}$.

However, from your question I deduce that you could be dealing with radiance in *wavelength units*. In which case, Wien's law gives us
$$ \lambda_{\rm max} = \frac{hc}{2.82kT}$$
and
$$f(\lambda)_{\rm max} = \frac{2hc^2}{(hc/2.82kT)^5}\left(\exp\left[\frac{hc}{(hc/2.82kT)kT}\right]-1\right)^{-1} = 7.1\times10^{-4}\,\frac{k^5}{h^4c^3} T^5$$
in units of W m$^{-2}$ sr$^{-1}$ m$^{-1}$.